# Meaning of Google Material Icons

Tags: google-material-icons

[Google Material icons](https://material.io/icons/) contain a "leak add" and "leak remove" icon. I have tried to find out what they are actually used for, but could not find any clue on the web page or anywhere else. Here is how they look:

[image]

Can anybody explain the meaning of these two icons? Is it used for memory leaks, information leaks, or has it to do with wifi?

Thanks

Comment: They're with the rest of the camera icons. Maybe light leaks ("lomography")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hint in the first comment I found the answer.

The two icons are referring to "light leaks". These are originally holes or gaps in a camera's body that allows light to "leak" onto the film or sensor. This causes artefacts that are used today intentionally as artistic effect. Various sources are offering light leak effects for photo and film editing.

[Wikipedia article on light leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_leak)